# CSS Navbar hover full height

Tags: html, css

So I am new in this HTML thing and I am experimenting with a navigation bar. With when I hover over a li/a element I get another color for the full height of the navigation bar.

[This is what I get first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpYPK.png)

```html
body{
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}

.header{
 width: 100%;
 height: 55px;
 background-color: #ecf0f1;
 text-align: right;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.navbar ul{
}
 .navbar ul li{
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%; 
 }
  .navbar ul li a{
   text-decoration: none;
   color: black;
   font-family: 'Franklin Gothic';
   padding: 50px;
   height: 100%;
  }

.navbar ul li:hover{
 background-color: #bdc3c7;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>HTML</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="header">
  <div class="navbar">
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And then I changed a few things in the code and came up with this ([Here is the second experiment result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9viEL.png)) (erasing `overflow:hidden;` and changed it with `line-height:55px;`)

I got the full height hover but there's a white gap between the browser window and my navigation bar.

```html
body{
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}

.header{
 width: 100%;
 height: 55px;
 background-color: #ecf0f1;
 text-align: right;
 line-height: 55px;
}

.navbar ul{
}
 .navbar ul li{
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%; 
 }
  .navbar ul li a{
   text-decoration: none;
   color: black;
   font-family: 'Franklin Gothic';
   padding: 50px;
   height: 100%;
  }

.navbar ul li:hover{
 background-color: #bdc3c7;
}
```

I know there's a bunch of similar questions like mine and I've read them before asking here, but I still don't get the result that I want.

Comment: one single piece of code would be great :D you know how to insert code snippet, so you can show real navbar here and people can help you without working out what to put together

Comment: @moped sorry sir didnt know thats how its work... wont do it again next time i post code... thankyou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go, your navbar needs margin removed, so check the code ..

EDIT: I also modified `a` a little bit, so it doesn't overflow navbar and fills full height of it.

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 55px;
  background-color: #ecf0f1;
  text-align: right;
  line-height: 55px;
}
.navbar ul {
  margin: 0;  /* <--- THIS IS WHAT REMOVES BLANK SPACE ABOVE/BELOW NAVBAR */
}
.navbar ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
}
.navbar ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-family: 'Franklin Gothic';
  padding: 0 50px; /* more proper use of padding */
  line-height: 55px; /* line-height to allow full clickable area */
  display: block; /* so the line-height can be applied */
}
.navbar ul li:hover {
  background-color: #bdc3c7;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>HTML</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <div class="navbar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">3</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">4</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

In your CSS , add

```
html,body {
margin: 0;
padding:0;
```

}

Comment: check his question, he already has `body {margin:0}` and the problem is in navbar itself